# TreeView Root Node Selected

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have this code to select first node of TreeView.  But when page loads the by default root node is other than first, I want to set the selected node as top most by default.  Here is my code in page load but it's not working:

```
Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = TreeView1.Nodes
If nodes.Count > 0 Then
  ' Select the root node
  TreeView1.SelectedNode = nodes(0)                        
End If
```

This gives the blue underline error on this line:

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode = nodes(0)
```

The error is:

> "Selected Node Property is read Only"

Please any one tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a node you need to set the selected property on the node itself:

```
nodes(0).Selected = true
```

Equally you can use:

```
nodes(0).Select()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 nodes(0).Selected
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.select.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net .SelectedNode is readonly you can only get but not set it using this property. You can use Node.Selected = true or Node.Selected = false to achive the same functionality!

Try this:

```
    Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = TreeView1.Nodes
          If nodes.Count > 0 Then                      
              ' Select the root node
                nodes(0).Selected = true
           End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<ARTICLE_REVIEW> reviewList = eb.ArticleReviewGetByUserOID(long.Parse(Session["User_OID"].ToString()));
            treeReviews.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach (ARTICLE_REVIEW review in reviewList)
            {

                TreeNode stepNode = new TreeNode();
                stepNode.Value = review.ID.ToString();
                stepNode.Text = review.TITLE;

                treeReviews.Nodes.Add(stepNode);
                treeReviews.ExpandAll();

        // Set the root node to be selected

                treeReviews.Nodes[0].Selected = true;
            }
```